# Большая проблема с юнити и mirror

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу игру *(по-типу "Robocraft" или "Crossout")*.

У меня есть префаб машины - просто `empty` с компонентами. При подключении к серверу или создании хоста появляется этот пустой объект, и на нём загружается чертёж. У объекта появляется миллион дочерних деталей. Я начал делать оружия для игры и столкнулся с проблемой: от этих созданных нельзя вызывать `[Command]` методы и, в том числе, `[Command(requiresAuthority = false)]` тоже не помогло, однако, эти методы можно вызывать от машины.

Я конечно могу с этим жить, но тогда нужно создать мега-гигантский класс, в котором будут лежать все методы для стрельбы и не только, а игре всего несколько месяцев, и уже есть порядка 5-и типов пушек, а дальше больше.

Я уже пробовал все и делать методы `[server]`, и пытался дать права пушкам убил неделю, но всё бесполезно. Я даже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Читать про SRP и в целом про SOLID. Вам не должно быть нужно создавать мегагигантские классы. Игровой контент должен быть вообще за пределами кодовой базы, то есть не в скриптах шарпа, а каких-нибудь ресурсах, например в json файлах. А код должен их подружать при старте игры. Вбивание контента прямо в код называется "хардкод" и является плохой практикой.

Comment: Я не это имею в виду, в общем у меня есть маленькие классы для всех пушек(они там наследуются друг от друга) у них в полях префабы которыми они стреляют. А мегагинатский класс который просто без полезен с хардокодом, всеми пулями всеми эффектами, и лишними данными приходится создавать из ситуации в которую меня ставит ассет миррор, он вообще ставит всю мою систему с ног на уши. Вы не так поняли.

Comment: Проблема в том что с этих маленьких классов нельзя слать комманды то есть вызывать методы [command] их можно слать только с самой машины, но ладно создали гигантский класс запихали туда все методы спавна всех пуль и не только. Но в комманд методы нельзя передать ссылки на префабы и это трындец. В этот мега класс нужно ещё и все префабы напихать!